# Using Square brackets [1] in bibliography instead of 1. by modifying .sty file

Tags: bibliographies

I have a .sty file with the following bibliography style:

```
\renewcommand\refname{\normalsize References \rm}
\setlength\bibindent{.3in}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section{\refname
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}%
      \list{\@arabic\c@enumiv .}
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{.25in}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pc}
  \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0.05pc}%{-0.06in}
  \setlength{\listparindent}{0in}
  \setlength{\itemindent}{0in}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.3cm}
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0in}
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m \normalsize}
```

How to fix it to get in the bibliography a "[1]" instead of "1."

MWE for the document is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,pdf]{article}

\begin{document}
    Testing~\cite{first}
\end{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
    \bibitem{first} Author et al., ``My Paper,'' Conference, 2014.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Are you really using `biblatex` as your tagging suggests? If so, you should use a different method. Please consider adding a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows the code in the context of your bibliography.

Comment: I added a full MWE with the bibliography definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearance of the label is controlled by `\list{\@arabic\c@enumiv .}`; You can change it in `\list{[\@arabic\c@enumiv]}`